# wpf data grid - moving from one cell to another cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

how to capture event when moving from one cell to another in same row.

Answer (score 0):

You get the [`CurrentCellChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcellchanged.aspx) event:

> [...] when the value of the CurrentCell property has changed.

You'd have to check you were still on the same row, but it should do what you want.